# Self.tableView.reloadData not working if there is no user tap or View change

Tags: ios, swift

I am having an issue; I have the following code that get execute in a IBAction and as you will see I have the code to execute reloadData of the tableView.  The issue is if I don't touch the screen (like a tap or change of the view) no data is displayed in the tableView but as soon as I touch the screen or move the cells (like just move them up and down) then the data appears.

The following image is the code that imports the contacts, save them in core data and loads them into an Array and execute reload data.

[image]

Here is the complete code of the ViewController where this issue is happening.

import UIKit
import CoreData
import AddressBook

class ContactsViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var tableviewContacts: UITableView!
//Public property that represent an array of the contacts added or copied by the user using the application
var contacts: [Contact] = []

//Public property that represent the context required to save the data in the persistance storage.
var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override  func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loadContacts()
    tableviewContacts.reloadData()
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contacts.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:cellContact = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellContact", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellContact
    let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelContact.text = contact.name + " " + contact.surname


    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        var contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
        var error: NSError?
        var handler: HACoreDataHandler = HACoreDataHandler()

        handler.context!.deleteObject(contact)

        handler.context!.save(&error)


        if(error != nil){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                Void in
            }

            alert.addAction(dismiss)

            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        contacts.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}

@IBAction func importContacts(sender: AnyObject) {
    let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
    if status == .Denied || status == .Restricted {
        // user previously denied, to tell them to fix that in settings
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "We need your permission to import your contacts to giftlog.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
            Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(dismiss)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    // open it

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let addressBook: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error)?.takeRetainedValue()
    if addressBook == nil {
        println(error?.takeRetainedValue())
        return
    }

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook) {
        granted, error in

        if !granted {
            // warn the user that because they just denied permission, this functionality won't work
            // also let them know that they have to fix this in settings
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Please grant access to your contact first by granting the acess to Giftlog in the privacy phone setting ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                Void in
            }

            alert.addAction(dismiss)

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        if let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {
            var handler: HACoreDataHandler = HACoreDataHandler()
            var error: NSError?
            for person:ABRecordRef in people{
                if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) != nil){
                    var contact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: handler.context!) as! Contact
                    contact.name = (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String)!
                    contact.surname = (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String)!

                    var phones : ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
                    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)>0){
                        let phoneUnmaganed = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, 0)
                        contact.phone = phoneUnmaganed.takeUnretainedValue() as! String
                    }

                    let emails: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue()
                    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails)>0){
                        let index = 0 as CFIndex
                        let emailAddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, index).takeRetainedValue() as! String
                        contact.email = emailAddress
                    }
                    handler.context!.save(&error)

                    if (error != nil){
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                        Void in
                        }
                        alert.addAction(dismiss)
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    } else {
                        self.contacts.append(contact)
                        self.tableviewContacts.reloadData()

                    } // else
              } //if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) != nil)

            } //for person:ABRecordRef in people

        } // if let people
    } // ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion
}

func loadContacts(){
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contact")
    let handler = HACoreDataHandler()
    var error: NSError?

    contacts = handler.context!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Contact]

    if(error != nil){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
            Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(dismiss)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

This image is the code that sets the label of each cell of the tableView.

[image]

Finally this is the image from the storyboard file of the view and the prototype cell
[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Post _code_. - And when you do, show the actual method so we can see how this code is being called.

Comment: This is just a hunch, there's not much else that I can do, but could you check if you're reloading the table view on the main thread? if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {NSLog(@"Main!")};

Comment: did you set the delegate and datasource properties on your tableview ?

Comment: This reminds me of an iOS bug last year where the cell's label wasn't drawn (visible) until the cell contents were redrawn due to the cell being selected/scrolled.